# Как считать подстроки , не обращая внимания на их наложение?

Tags: python

Допустим наш язык - Python , и мы используем метод `.count()`
Нам нужно считать количество подстрок из строки, например:`.count('+---+')`
 в `'+---+---+'` .Ответ будет равный 1, но мне нужно, чтобы несмотря на наложение выдало 2, т.е, чтобы метод видел строку, как `'+---+' '+---+'`, а не `'+---+' '---+'`. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def substr_count(string, substring):
    # Начальная позиция поиска — первый символ строки
    f = 0
    count = 0

    while True:
        # Ищем первую попавшуюся позицию нужной нам подстроки,
        # продолжая с предыдущей позиции, на котором остановился поиск
        f = string.find(substring, f)
        # Если f будет -1, значит больше ничего не нашлось
        if f < 0:
            break
        # Записываем найденный результат
        count += 1
        # Сдвигаемся на один символ, чтобы find в следующей
        # итерации не стал повторно искать ту же самую позицию
        f += 1
        # Для сравнения: если вместо этого написать f += len(substring),
        # то получится то же самое поведение, что и у стандартного .count()

    # Когда вышли из цикла, возвращаем число найденных подстрок
    return count


print(substr_count('+---+---+', '+---+'))
# → 2

print(substr_count('<--<<--<<>>-->>-->-->>-->', '<--<<'))
# → 2

print(substr_count('<--<<--<<>>-->>-->-->>-->', '>>-->'))
# → 3
```

Comment: Мне кажется лучше двигать на `len(substring)-1`, тогда условие именно стрелками и плюсами будет выполнить. Такое не будет работать, только если наложение может быть внутренним.

Comment: @Axenow ни в одном из упоминавшихся условий не сказано о необходимости двигать именно на столько, будет сказано - обновлю

Answer (score 2):

В общем случае получается так:

```
astring="+---+---+"
searchfor = "+---+"
count = 0

def proc(a, s, c):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i:(i+len(s))] == s:            
            c += 1
    return c

print("Number of times "+ searchfor+" occures is: "+ str(proc(astring, searchfor, count)))
```

На выходе будет:

```
Number of times +---+ occures is: 2
```

Comment: В 6.5 раз медленнее моего решения :)

Comment: @andreymal - возможно. но мое универсальнее, потому как просто работает со списками, и так же найдет `[2,3]` в `[1,2,3,4,2,2,3]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def a_count(sub_string: str, string: str) -> int:

    counter = 0
    start_position = string.find(sub_string)
    while index != -1:
        counter += 1
        start_position = string.find(sub_string, start_position + 1)

    return counter

s_string = '<<<<>>--><--<<--<<>>>--><<<<<'
print(a_count('<--<<', s_string) + a_count('>>-->', s_string))
# 4
```

---

<s>В данном конкретном случае это можно реализовать так:</s>

```
s = '+---+---+'
print(s.replace('+', '++').count('+---+'))
```

Но это костыли. Гораздо интересней другая задача

> Посчитать количество стрелок в строке `b = '<--<<--<<>>-->>-->-->>-->'` где стрелкой считается либо `<--<<` либо `>>-->`

Comment: Это все пример для понимания, на самом же деле нужен алгоритм для произвольного случая

Comment: @MickeyU, Ну собственно поэтому и названо костылем ))) Добавьте пример со стрелками в вопрос, думаю будет интересней.

Comment: Это решение не будет работать даже для строки поиска `+--+----+`, потому что исходная строка будет полностью изменена.

Comment: Ну почему "даже", не стоит усложнять задачу до абсурда, добавляя разделители с середину патерна. Хотя справедливости ради от определения данного в самом решении как "костыль" не отказываюсь